# Angular 2 route with parameter acts as wildcard route

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I have an angular app with multiple Modules, which each define some routes.

**App (base module) uses this AppRoutingModule:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'user', loadChildren: 'app/user/user.module#UserModule'},
  {path: 'exchange', loadChildren: 'app/exchange/exchange.module#ExchangeModule'},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full'},
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

**User Module Router:**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(
    [{
      path: '', component: UserComponent,
      children: [
        {path: '', component: UserProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuardService]},
        {path: 'login', component: UserLoginComponent},
        {path: 'register', component: UserRegisterComponent},
        {path: 'confirm/:confirmcode', component: UserConfirmMailComponent},
        {path: 'logout', component: UserLogoutComponent}
      ]
    }]
  )],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class UserRoutingModule {
}
```

**Exchange Module Router:**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(
    [{
      path: '', component: ExchangeComponent,
      children: [
        {path: '', component: ExchangeListComponent},
        {path: ':exchange-name', component: ExchangeDetailComponent},
        {path: ':exchange-name/:baseCode', component: ExchangeSelectionComponent},
        {path: ':exchange-name/:baseCode/:targetCode', component: ExchangePairComponent},
      ]
    }]
  )],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ExchangeRoutingModule {
}
```

I can now use the route `http://localhost:4200/exchange/Sample/Base` for accessing `ExchangeSelectionComponent` component as expected.

But when I navigate to `http://localhost:4200/user/confirm/` and accidentally missed to add the required parameter `confirmcode`, instead of an Invalid-Route-Error I get matched to the same `ExchangeSelectionComponent`-route as above. 
Also when I try to open `http://localhost:4200/thispagedoesnotexist` I get to the `ExchangeDetailComponent` with `exchange-name = thispagedoesnotexist`.

It seems that everything below `/exchange/` also gets matched to the base root `/`.

Why is that and how can I avoid that behaviour?
I thought that every route defined in a route inside `routeChildren` only gets lazy loaded, when the corresponding parent-route is accessed and until then is not even touched.

I use Angular 5.2. Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: this line in your example is not complete


      `{path: 'exchange', loadChildren:'app/exchange/exchange.module#`

can you please write it correctly so we would know what's there.

Comment: sorry, fixed it

Comment: np, have you by any means imported exchange module in app.module ?

Comment: yes I have. I added them first as normal modules and then updated it for lazy loading. after removing the imported from AppModule that behaviour is as expected. thanks!

Comment: that's good news, yes i will write this as answer, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guessing that the ExchangeModule is imported in the app.module and thus it's route definition is being resolved instead of the lazy loaded ones.

```
path: '', component: ExchangeComponent
```

Make sure that the modules are lazyloaded and not imported in app.module, this can be confirmed by quickly checking the app.module file or by checking the network tab and look for new loaded chunks when you access a route that should be lazyloaded, if a new chunk wasn't loaded then your module has been imported in app.module and wasn't lazyloaded.